# Looking for a Simple Linux Monitoring Agent

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp

I'm looking for a simple, easy to install, works on all of the major linux distros, works with SNMP, monitoring agent software.

It should simply report the disk usage, server load, process list, uptime, memory usage etc with SNMP.

Any suggestions?

Oktay

edit - to describe what I'm trying to achieve in a more simplistic way:

I'm looking to install a tiny software on the servers I want to get real time statistics from and ability to connect that software to get those statistics.

Comment: The link in the previous comment references a thread with the selected answer referring to Nagios.  While I would consider Nagios a good choice to use, it is not "Simple" in the way I believe ispirto asks.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm looking for a simple, tiny agent that's easy to install and give me ability to connect via SNMP to get status of the servers.

Comment: http://mathias-kettner.com/check_mk.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found what I was looking for: http://www.webnms.com/linux-monitor/index.html

It's tiny and even has a tiny webserver to display statistics, also works with SNMP.

**I'm however open to other suggestions**, this badboy does not show the uptime correctly and it's not open source.

Oktay

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Monit. Its very lightweight and monitors everything you mentioned. Additionally you can configure it so that it sends out email alerts when there are problems and it tries to fix the problem which has occurred.

Not sure if you have a web server on any of your servers but there is also M/Monit which provides you a web interface to view the status of all servers running Monit.

I have been using it for almost a year on my RHEL servers and I love it. Monit is free but M/Monit requires a small one time fee of about $150 ish.

Answer (score 0):

[Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) is probably "the standard" for SNMP on Linux. It can be freely extended with scripts in pretty much any language.

Answer (score -2):

I think Nagios is the better and most complete solution to your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I believe CACTI is the simplest among all monitoring tools.